# Retrofit - getting null error response body (MalformedJsonException)

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to get error response body in `onFailure(RetrofitError error)`, but getting `null`.

I am using the header `Accept: text/plain` for requests and from response I receive `Content-Type: text/plain` and can see body as text if I set `LogLevel.FULL`. Moreover, `error.getResponse().getStatus()` gives me correct status code.

But when I perform `error.getBody()` or `error.getResponse.getBody()` it returns `null`. Inside `error` I see that `successType` is `java.lang.String`, so I assume it should give me `String`, but `error.getCause()` shows me

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   6 path $

Also, `error.getKind()` is `CONVERSION`, which stands for

> /** An exception was thrown while (de)serializing a body. */

but I expect to get kind as `HTTP`

Question is why does it tries to convert into JSON when all headers are using `text/plain` and `successType` is `String`?
I need to get my response as plain text.

Code snippet:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(url)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setClient(new CustomOkHttpClient())
        .setRequestInterceptor(new TransactionsRequestInterceptor())
        .build();

TransactionsRestClient httpClient = restAdapter.create(TransactionsRestClient.class);
httpClient.createNewTransaction(request, new retrofit.Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void success(String transactionId, Response response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // error.getBody() is null
    }
}
public interface TransactionsRestClient {
    @POST("/transactions")
    void createNewTransaction(@Body TransactionRequest request, Callback<String> transactionId);
}

public class TransactionsRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader(HOST, host);
        request.addHeader(TOKEN, token);
        request.addHeader(ACCEPT, TEXT);
        request.addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, JSON);
    }
```

Logged requests/responses:

```
 ---> HTTP POST $url
Host: $host
Accept: text/plain
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 133
$request_body
---> END HTTP (133-byte body)

<--- HTTP 202 $url //202 is expected
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 16:08:46 GMT
Server: spray-can/1.3.1
Content-Length: 50
Connection: keep-alive
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1432138139875
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1432138140004
The record for test10 is not currently authorized. // this is body I have to get
<--- END HTTP (50-byte body)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because Retrofit is a [REST client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and expects responses to be in JSON not plain text. Your response seems to have returned as `null` which is not JSON

Comment: REST supports plain text as well, not only json. Response can be seen when doing full level logging of retrofit requests/responses and displayed as text there, but not accessible

Comment: Please post the relevant code you use to make the request

Comment: You should post you Android code, which is the source of your problem (and solution). Please don't post code in external sources, as they may expire

Answer (score 1):

By default Retrofit reads the response as a JSON and parses it automatically. You have to change it's default behavior.

[This blog post](http://tsuharesu.com/get-retrofit-response-as-string/) might be helpful, and suggests you to get your String response as:

```
new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes());
```

Comment: Anyways, post your relevant code, so we can try to help if you have issues with the converter

Comment: this example is for `Response` instance, but I'm struggling with `RetrofitError` instance. Is just gives me `error.getBoy()` as null, so any further casting and getting bytes will throw NPE

Comment: You're getting an error because Retrofits assumes you're receiving a JSON response and throwing an error when trying to convert it. You must not covert this response, which is what the blog post says but doesn't explain much how to avoid using GSON. Please post your relevant code

Comment: @ViMatviichuk Your response isn't valid json, you should follow the advice above.

Comment: my response is text, but not json. I want to have it as String, but not `JsonElement`. Server returns me text and I need to get text, but not json. REST is not about json only, it supports all HTTP content formats, like plain text, json, xml, any other custom types and etc. In my case I just need text

Answer (score 1):

In your code `new RestAdapter.Builder()` you do not specify a Converter (`setConverter()`).

Looking at Retrofit code, more specifically at [RestAdapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/f6878a5ccbe7505fcf44fa7063c72e6434493f75/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java) and [Platform](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/f6878a5ccbe7505fcf44fa7063c72e6434493f75/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/Platform.java) I checked that if you do not specify a Converter it will use GSON as default:

```
@Override Converter defaultConverter() {
  return new GsonConverter(new Gson());
}
```

I believe the solution is to create a Custom Converter (extending Converter class) and do nothing with your response, just returning the raw String.

[Here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-replace-the-integrated-json-converter/)'s an example on how to create your own Converter.

Comment: that is going to change my request converter, while my request has to remain json. I need to send json and to get text. Custom converter will not work in this case, as request serialization will fail. I assumed that retrofit uses body parser based on http headers, but mine headers are `text/plain` and still getting json exception

Comment: This is the converter for your response

Comment: my success response is in json, which is correct, but my failure response is in plain text. Anyway, I used StringConverter and got http-400 (bad request)

Comment: If you solved the issue please post here to let us know

Comment: as a solution, we're going to switch all back-end services to json. How to get text from error body, but not json - still do not know. Well check out retrofit's source code a bit later a post an answer